# asp.net MVC - Videos with size more than 10MB doesn't play

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

```
 <httpRuntime 
executionTimeout="3600"
maxRequestLength="102400"
useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="false"
minFreeThreads="8"
minLocalRequestFreeThreads="4"
appRequestQueueLimit="100"
enableVersionHeader="true"
/>
```

If I use above code in web.config file,  I am able upload the large size videos but videos doesn't play at all. The video plays if size is lesser than 8 MB.

I have tried following code.

```
  <video width="100%" height="100%" controls autoplay>
  <source src="~/@Model.video_Path" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
```

Comment: what is the status code of the response? Is it 413 or 500 or something else?

Comment: On my streaming project the entry in web.config for the httpRuntime looks like: <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" enableVersionHeader="false" /> and it can even play 4GB files in the video-tag. But i run the aps.net site on a IIS 8.5  (Windows Server 2012 R2) maybe it depends on it

Answer (score 0):

If you are running IIS7 or later, you might also have to increase the maxAllowedContentLength, which basically limits the size of responses sent to the client.  It should go in your web.config file.

This is about 1GB:

```
<system.webServer>
   <security>
      <requestFiltering>
         <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
      </requestFiltering>
   </security>
 </system.webServer>
```

Comment: Thank you for quick response.

Comment: I am running IIS7 . In my web.config file has already contain the above code. but i am facing same problem.  Eg: http://localhost:52353/Uploads/Video/test.mp4  if the size of video test.mp4 is 4MB it is playing on browser. if the video size is more than 12MB it is not playing the video.

Comment: What happens if you try to download the video, not play it?  Does it download successfully?  If so, then the problem is not the server, but rather the browser/video player I would think.

Comment: when i try to play the video in simple html file it is playing. but the same video in my application in not playing. my code   <html>
  <video width="100%" height="100%" controls autoplay>
                    <source src="test1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                </video>  
</html>

Comment: But can you download the video in your application?  We need to know if the server is not serving the file if it's too large, or if it's just the player refusing to play it.

Comment: we are not providing the any downloading option for video. just user will play the video on browser.

Comment: No, but you can take the URL of the video and paste it into your browser address bar and press enter ....

Comment: direct video url in browser it is playing.  file:///E:/test.mp4 and in html file file:///E:/test.html it is playing. but in application url  localhost:52353/Uploads/Video/test.mp4 it is not working

Comment: Take this URL: localhost:52353/Uploads/Video/test.mp4 and paste it into you browser address bar and press enter.  What happens?  Keep the dev console open and view the network tab.  What response does the request return?

Comment: yes , from browser video is downloading. but the server is refused to play the video because of large size. in my console tab `Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type video/mp4: "http://localhost:52353/Uploads/AssetVideo/abc.mp4".
Navigated to http://localhost:52353/Uploads/AssetVideo/abc.mp4`

Comment: Ok, sorry I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

```
<video width="100%" height="100%" controls autoplay>
  <source src="~/@Model.video_Path" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
```

this Part is may cause a problem  and it not recommended 
You could simple send the video  as a byte array to the src tag in source in video tag

go to controller  and Make Method Like this

```
public ActionResult MyAction(string FilePath)
        {
            try
            {
        FilePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/Videos/") + FilePath);

        byte[] myVideo = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(FilePath);
        return new FileContentResult(myVideo, "video/mp4");
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return View("_NotFoundVideo");
            }


        }
```

then go to The src attribute in source tag in the video tag 
and use @Url.Action() so you get the byte array of the video  as filecontentresult
like this

```
 @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            @if (item.Path != null || item.Name != null)
            {
                <td>
                    <h5> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)</h5> <br />
                    <video style="width:900px; height:300px;" controls>
                        @*<source src="~/UpLoads/Videos/@item.Path" type="video/mp4" />*@
                        <source src="@Url.Action("MyAction", "Blobs", new { FilePath =item.Path })" type="video/mp4" />
                 <h1 class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></h1>
                    </video>
                </td>
            }
```